# Time difference in PHP using timezone function?

Tags: php

I am trying to find a way to display a difference in time between two locations using timezone function in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

lets say I have chosen UK and China from the link above and I can display the times of the locations on a php page but how can I show a time difference between these two locations?

i.e. in the UK is 12:49 and in the China is 18:49. I need to show the difference between these two values in hours!

any help would be great.

EDIT: here is how I display the current time for specific location in PHP:

```
<div style="visibility:hidden;"><?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');
echo  'Current Time In Moscow: ' . date('H:i:s.A') . PHP_EOL ;
?>

<div style="visibility:hidden;"><?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Shanghai');
echo  'Current Time In Beijing: ' . date('H:i:s.A') . PHP_EOL ;
?>
```

I have also found this link on Google but I am not sure how to go about with that: http://kukunotes.wordpress.com/2013/04/28/php-find-time-difference-between-two-countries-by-country-code/

Comment: Okay, you've told us the requirements. Now show your code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function get_timezone_offset( $origin_tz, $remote_tz ) {
    $timezone1 = new DateTimeZone( $origin_tz );
    $timezone2 = new DateTimeZone( $remote_tz );

    $datetime1 = new DateTime("now", $timezone1);
    $datetime2 = new DateTime("now", $timezone2);

    $offset = $timezone1->getOffset($datetime1) - $timezone2->getOffset($datetime2);
    return $offset;
}

$offset = get_timezone_offset( 'Europe/London', 'Asia/Shanghai' );

// convert offset to hours
echo $offset/3600;
```

Comment: How about if we got more than two locations?

Comment: Yes, something was wrong with my previous answer, updated answer is working